# Frobenius method giving the trivial solution-why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Second order ordinary differential equation with variable coefficients]

Hello! I try to solve the above equation, where u=f(s,r) and p=g(s,r) are Laplace transformed functions, H1, H2, H3 are expressions of the Laplace transform parameter s and r  is variable. I use the Frobenius method, since r=0 is a regular singular point, but I get the trivial solution. Why does this happen? Any other ideas for finding an analytic solution?

Comment: Try using latex.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).